# How to change the count of a for loop during the loop

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, dynamic

I'm trying to change the number of items in array, over which a for loop is running, during the for loop, with the objective that this changes the number of loops. In a very simplified version, the code would look something like this:

```
var loopArray: [Int] = []

loopArray.append(1)
loopArray.append(2)
loopArray.append(3)
loopArray.append(4)
loopArray.append(5)

for x in 0..<Int(loopArray.count) {
    print(x)
    if x == 4 {
        loopArray.append(6)
    }
}
```

When running this code, 5 numbers are printed, and while the number 6 is added to the Array, the `loopArray.count` does not seem to update. How can I make the `.count` dynamic?
This is a very simplified example, in the project I'm working on, appending numbers to the array depends on conditions that may or may not be met.

I have looked for examples online, but have not been able to find any similar cases. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sfung3 gives the correct way to do what you want, but I think there needs to be a bit of explanation as to why your solution doesn't work

The line

```
for x in 0..<Int(loopArray.count)
```

only evaluates `loopArray.count` once, the first time it is hit. This is because of the way `for` works. Conceptually a `for` loop iterates through the elements of a sequence. The syntax is something like

```
for x in s
```

where

- s is a sequence, give it type `S`
- x is a let constant (you can also make it a `var` but that is not relevant to the current discussion) with type `S.Element`

So the bit after the `in` is a sequence - any sequence. There's nothing special about the use of `..<` here, it's just a convenient way to construct a sequence of consecutive integers. In fact, it constructs a [Range](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range) (btw, you don't need the cast to `Int`, `Array.count` is already an `Int`).

The range is only constructed when you first hit the loop and it's effectively a constant because `Range` is a value type.

If you don't want to use Joakim's answer, you could create your own reference type (class) that conforms to `Sequence` and whose elements are `Int` and update the upper bound each time through the loop, but that seems like a lot of work to avoid a while loop.

Comment: It's not my answer, I only edited it. :)

Comment: Many thanks for the additional explanation, very helpful

Answer (score 2):

you can use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.

```
var i = 0
while i < loopArray.count {
    print(i)
    if i == 4 {
        loopArray.append(6)
    }
    
    i += 1
}
```

which prints
`0 1 2 3 4 5`